# ROS Installation hangs building rosbag recorder.cpp.o

Tags: ros, rosbag, raspberrypi, build-from-source, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried already a couple of times and it always hangs building the rosbag recorder.cpp.o object with no error message. I've been waiting for hours but the installation process does not contiune. The last message is:

[ 40% ] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/recorder.cpp.o

Has anyone a clue, why is this happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223128/ros-installation-hangs-building-rosbag-recorder.cpp.o/) by [sapient84](https://answers.ros.org/users/25429/sapient84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-26**:
What sort of computer are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a Raspberry Pi and yes, it was only taking too long. I actually have already the Raspberry overclocked but it was anyway too slow. It took over one and a half day to install ros. I just needed to be more pacient... I apologize for this useless question... Thank anyway ahendrix!

---

Originally posted by [sapient84](https://answers.ros.org/users/25429/sapient84/) with karma: 51 on 2015-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0